# Can't compare array length at two points in time when push() updates the array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm needing to compare the previous state of an array length with a later state (not referring to state syntax). I thought the task was as simple as assigning the variable to a new variable at the point in time you want to capture, then just use that variable to compare with the main variable later, i.e;

```
let x = [1, 2];
const y = x;
function test() {
    x.push(3, 4);
    console.log(x.length > y.length);
}
test();
```

But for some reason this returns

```
false
```

I only have this issue when using `push()`. As soon as `x.push(3, 4)` is executed for some reason `y` is updated to have the same values as `x` after pushing in more data. This confuses me because they're in different scopes and executed at different times? Is there something magical I don't understand about `push()`?

Comment: Basically, `y` is a reference to `x`, not a copy. Use `slice()` or `const y = [...x];` to make a copy.

Comment: Interesting, so the state of an array is almost like a scopeless object (reference). I'm a little loose with my understanding of the spread operator, how does it function to make the array a copy exactly?

Comment: If you want to compare just a previous length, then store just the previous length: let `prevLength = x.length;`.  Arrays are objects in Javascript and objects are assigned by pointer.  So, when you do `const y = x`, you now have a pointer to the same object in both variables `y` and `x`. They literally point at the same object so, of course, when you change that object, both variables are looking at the same object so they see the change. This has nothing to do with scope. The array's length, is a number which is a primitive in Javascript so when you assign it, you get a separate static copy.

Comment: This is great thank you, `const y = [...x];` was certainly the most helpful solution. Should post it as a response.